# Cannot return vector containing derived pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

Okay, so to illustrate the issue I am having I will show some (pseudo) code.

Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Animal : public GameObject;

class Player : public GameObject;

class GameObject : public ObjectInterface;

class ObjectInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~ObjectInterface() = default;
    virtual vec3 GetPosition() = 0;
}
```

Now I also hold some "object context", which holds collections of certain game objects.

```
class ContextObject
{
     // they implement ObjectInterface
     vector<shared_ptr<Animal>> animals;
     vector<shared_ptr<Player>> players; 
}
```

Now I have a `TargetSelector` class, which works directly with the `ObjectInterface` only.

```
class TargetSelector
{
    // this is somehow not possible, although `animals` are a subclass of `ObjectInterface`
    vector<shared_ptr<Model::ObjectInterface>>& GetAvailableTargets()
    {
        return context->animals; // context is some `ObjectContext`
    }
}
```

I would expect the above code to work, since an `Animal` is of the type `ObjectInterface`. But instead I get an error saying it cannot convert from an `vector<shared_ptr<Animal>>` to an `vector<shared_ptr<ObjectInterface>>`. Is this even suppose to work?

Could someone explain me why I cannot do this kind of polymorphism and if possible a nice solution so I can make this work.

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `shared_ptr<Base>` and `shared_ptr<Derived>` are different types. You can convert one to the other, but you can't alias them.  If you want to make a `vector<shared_ptr<ObjectInterface>>` you will have to fill it with copies of the `shared_ptr<Animal>` etc.

Comment: Maybe you should store `shared_ptr<ObjectInterface>` in all cases, and `animals` can cast on use if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect the above code to work, since an `Animal` is of the type `ObjectInterface`.

Unfortunately, class templates don't work that way.

Given

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

Derived d;
Base& bref = d; // OK.
Base  b = d;    // OK.
```

However, given

```
template <tpename T> Foo {};

Foo<Derived> d;
Foo<Base>& bref = d; // Not OK
Foo<Base> b = d;     // Not OK.
```

`Derived` is a sub-type of `Base` does not imply `Foo<Derived>` is a sub-type of `Foo<Base>`.

That analogy applies to `shared_ptr` too. Your problem is compounded by use of another layer of class template. `shared_ptr<Derived>` is not a sub-type of `shared_ptr<Base>`. Never mind being able to use `vector<shared_ptr<Derived>>` when a `vector<shared_ptr<Base>>` is exepcted.

You can use `vector<shared_ptr<ObjectInterface>>` in all the places and make sure to cast to the appropriate `shared_ptr` type before using it.

Check out the various `pointer_cast` functions at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me, it makes sense now!